# How to make path dynamic on an Ajax call when calling a PHP server-side code

Tags: php, ajax

How to make a path to be dynamic on an Ajax Call, when I run the code locally it can only work when the URL path is **"/WebsiteFolder/assets/mail/contact_me.php"** and when it hosted on cPanel it can only work when the URL path is **"/assets/mail/contact_me.php"** , how to make the path dynamic?

```
$.ajax({
url: "/WebsiteFolder/assets/mail/contact_me.php",
type: "POST",
data: {
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    message: message,
},
cache: false,
success: function () {
    // Success message
  
},
error: function (xhr, status, error) {
    // Fail message

},
complete: function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $this.prop("disabled", false); // Re-enable submit button when AJAX call is complete
    }, 1000);
},
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [relative-path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp).

Remove the preceding `/`.

Instead of

`"/WebsiteFolder/assets/mail/contact_me.php"`

you will have

`"assets/mail/contact_me.php"`